# react native login api jwt auth basic

Tags: api, react-native, authentication

I need help, I must login in React Native by calling an API
with this structure

URL: `/api/a/login`

Parameters: data
value: `{
"user": "juan",
"userid": "123",
"passw": "000"
}`

type: GET

with basic authentication using JWT

How can I call this api with those parameters from React Native
Thank you.

Comment: Can you please share the minimal working example.

Comment: The information they give me is that the API is already on a server
and I can only make requests type GET and requires different parameters for the endpoint of login need the parameter "data"
that carries these values {"user": "juan", "userid": "123", "passw": "000"}

what I need is to know how I can consume the API that I can only make GET requests and requires parameters from React Native

Comment: login() {
    fetch (Api/a/login',{
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Accept: 'application/json',
          Authorization', 'Basic ' + "here should go a token or parameters"
  //'Authorization', 'Basic ' + base64.encode(this.state.user+ ":" + this.state.userid+ ":" + this.state.password)
        }

Comment: body: JSON.stringify({   // I don't know if I need you to wear this "body"
         user: this.state.user,
  userid: this.state.userid,
         password: this.state.password
      }),
    }).then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseData) =>{
          console.log("LoginData:-" + JSON.stringify(responseData));
       }).done();
  }

Comment: Example: https://pastebin.com/e9AerS7w

Answer (score 0):

You can use [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) to make HTTP calls. You can attach your auth JWT in the headers field to call the API.

Here's a minimal example using axios to make a GET request.

```
const axios = require("axios")
axios.get('/api/a/login', {
    params: {
        value: {
        "user": "juan",
        "userid": "123",
        "passw": "000"
        }
    },
    headers: {
         jwt: your_jwt_here
    }
})
```

Comment: Can you help me by looking at this example, thanks                                                              https://pastebin.com/e9AerS7w